# bash/shell script not reading second argument

Tags: shell, unix

this is simple script which i want to read first and second argument somehow its not reading the second argument and throwing error stating pass the value.

Here is the script //I want to clone the git

```
$cat test.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash

clone () {
  git clone $2
}

case $1
in
   clone) clone ;;

       *) echo "Invalid Argument passed" ;;
esac
```

#### Running the script

```
$./test.sh clone https://github.com/sameerxxxxx/test.git/
fatal: You must specify a repository to clone.

usage: git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]

    -v, --verbose         be more verbose
    -q, --quiet           be more quiet
    --progress            force progress reporting
```

Comment: Your script calls the shell function `clone()` without arguments...

Comment: And to add to alexis' comment, the argument $2 within your function refer to the arguments passed to the function, not to the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call your function `clone`, you have to pass the arguments to it.

```
clone() {
    git clone "$1"
}
...
clone) clone "$2";;
```

Note that the function's positional parameters are numbered separately from the script itself.

Comment: @latech, always, _always_ parenthesize those `$variable` when you're programming in the shell: if the `variable` contains a string with a space in it, using `$variable` when calling a function/command will produce as many arguments to the calls as there are spaces in the string, plus one.

Comment: @latech, also consider using `set -u` early in your scripts: should you have used it, the script would blow up in an attempt to call `clone $2` with an undefined variable `2`—supposedly hinting you at the root cause. All in all, looks like you did not bother to follow at least some basic tutorial on shell scripting, and just doing copying-and-pasting from SO. Please reconsider your approach to problem solving.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

clone () {
  git clone $1
}

case $1
in
   clone) clone $2 ;;

       *) echo "Invalid Argument passed" ;;
esac
```

`https://github.com/sameerxxxxx/test.git/` is the 2nd parameter passed to `test.sh`, so `clone $2 ;;` instead of `clone ;;`.

For `clone $2`, `$2` is the 1st parameter passed to the function `clone`, so `git clone $1` instead of `git clone $2`.