# Trouble reading second argument in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need to pass argument for commit function. When I do the commit through

```
./test.sh commit -m "first"
```

its not really committing it. believe somehow I am not passing right argument parameter either in case or function.

Here is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

clone () {
  git clone $1
}

commit () {
  git commit $*
}

case $1
in
   clone) clone $2 ;;
   commit) commit $2 ;;

       *) echo "Invalid Argument passed" ;;
esac
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do $? $0 $1 $2 mean in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29258603/608639), [What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5163144), etc. Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: @jww: One could argue that's the case, but OP clearly knows what `$1`, `$2` are, but not know how to shift args. A dupe involving `shift` would be more appropriate here

Comment: The question looks so similar to your last one - [bash/shell script not reading second argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52818885/5291015)

Comment: @Inian - Yes, agreed. [Grzegorz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29258643/608639) looked pretty good because it talked about how arguments can move around in seemingly unexpected ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments are processed like this by bash:

```
./test.sh commit -m "first" 

0: ./test.sh
1: commit
2: -m
3: first
```

So your `"first"` is actually argument `$3`.

Comment: Thank you so much for all..really appreciate your help. so my code looks seems ok ? But somehow its not working yet. strangely i have to run twice add and commit to make this works, i believe i missing something.                                                                   commit () {
      git commit $1 $2 
} 
case $1
in
   clone)  clone $2 ;;
   commit) commit $2 $3 ;;

       *) echo "Invalid Argument passed" ;;

esac

Comment: Hi, I was merely answering the parameters problem.  As for git itself, I do not know git enough to provide a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

To safely support multiple arguments (including ones with special characters) the function bodies should be

```
git clone "$@"
```

and

```
git commit "$@"
```

.

For the same reasons, the `case` code should be:

```
case $1 in
    clone)  clone "${@:2}" ;;
    commit) commit "${@:2}" ;;
    *)      echo "Invalid Argument passed" ;;
esac
```

In the functions, `"$@"` expands to all the function arguments, safely quoted so they are not subject to word splitting or expansions.

In the `case` statement, `${@:2}` expands to the list of command line arguments after the first one, safely quoted.

For more information see [Handling positional parameters [Bash Hackers Wiki]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams).